# Call non-static function in constructor initialization list, C++

Tags: c++, optimization, constructor

I am currently optimizing my code, and I came to a point where I was tempted to use the following pattern when initializing my class:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass(int x) :
        _x(x),
        _collection(createCollection())
    {
    }

    int functionThatDependsOnTheStateOfTheClass() const
    {
        return _x;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> createCollection() const
    {
        std::vector<int> collection;

        // The collection is dependent on _x somehow.
        collection.push_back(functionThatDependsOnTheStateOfTheClass());

        return collection:
    }

    const int _x;
    const std::vector<int> _collection;
};
```

I absolutely understand that it is dangerous to make the code implicitly dependent on the initialization order like this, but is the code wrong in any other way?

Note that the code above is very simplified. The reasons why I would like to do it are:

1. I want to have _collection marked as const.
2. The *functionThatDependsOnTheStateOfTheClass()* is one of the most called functions in my program (according to my profiler), so I would prefer to not create an overhead by passing the state of the class as function parameters.

So my question is: Should I avoid this pattern like the plague, or can it be acceptable in some circumstances?

Comment: Passing `x` by parameter is the best approach in my opinion. I disagree that there would be any actual overhead, you would be surprised at what compiler optimizers can do thesedays, likely it would all be inlined anyway.

Comment: Are you *sure* that passing the state in would be an overhead?  Remember that passing `this` will be an overhead too, and that you may save the cost of  indirecting through `this`.  Obviously, you would keep a member function `functionThatDependsOnTheStateOfTheClass` which just calls an overload with suitable arguments.

Comment: @Dai In my example code, the required parameters consists of a single int. In my real code however, there are 7 parameters, and two of them needs to be passed by reference since they are not primitives types. Do you still think they would be inlined automatically without any overhead?

Comment: @4-bit - you can only tell if that would make a difference by measuring.  So far I have correctly managed to intuit performance bottlenecks in a piece of code twice without measurement - since 1980.

Answer (score 5):

Right now your code is well defined. [The order of initialization of nonstatic data members of a class is](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#13):

> Then, nonstatic data members shall be initialized in the order they
>   were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order
>   of the mem-initializers).

And because `_x` is declared before `_collection`, `_x` will have been initialized and thus can be used in `functionThatDependsOnTheStateOfTheClass()`.

Comment: Agreed.  I think this would worth some essays in the comments explaining the dependencies (one in the function, another near the member variables, and a third for the constructor).  But keeping the collection `const` while not killing performance (and not violating DRY) probably makes it worthwhile.